# Where can I find a picture of a billboard from Indonesian campaign against toplessness?

Tags: clothing, indonesia

Years ago I saw a picture on Wikipedia of an old billboard in Indonesia or a nearby country telling women not to expose their breasts. It was part of a Westernization or religious campaign.

I cannot find that picture again. Do you know campaign exactly was that and how I can find the picture of the billboard?

Comment: Southeast Asia is a big place. Equating Indonesia with entire region of SEA is like equating Germany with whole of Europe.

Comment: It was for sure not a Westernization campaign. More likely a back to the Stone Age religious campaign. Could be Indonesia, but more likely Malaysia.